# docker nginx-reverse proxy and nginx php-fpm webserver, upstream failed

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy

I have two docker compose setups on the same machine.

One setup has an nginx reverse proxy setup and the other one hosts an nginx webserver with php-fpm.

When opening the ip address of the webserver with its corresponding port, I do get to see the page's web content. However, when I try to use the domain name, the reverse proxy tells me that the upstream failed.

I have another setup running with apache and the reverse proxy of that one does work.

The setups:

Reverse proxy default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /tmp/acme_challenge;
    }


    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    # all ssl related config moved to ssl.conf
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;

    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://webserver_nginx:80/;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        proxy_read_timeout  1200s;

        client_max_body_size 0;
    }
}
```

Reverse proxy docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: 'nginx-service'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
      - /tmp/acme_challenge:/tmp/acme_challenge
    networks:
      - nginx_reverse_proxy
    restart: always

networks:
  nginx_reverse_proxy:
    name: network_nginx_reverse_proxy
    external: true
```

The webserver setup:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    webserver_nginx:
        #image: nginx:latest
        build: ./nginx/
        ports:
            - "${WEBSERVER_PORT}:80"
        volumes:
            - ${WEBSERVER_FILES_PATH}:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - db
            - php
        networks:
            - webserver_nginx
            - nginx_reverse_proxy
        depends_on:
            - php
        restart: always
    php:
        build: ./php-fpm/
        expose:
            - 9000
        volumes:
            - ${WEBSERVER_FILES_PATH}:/var/www/html/
        networks:
            - webserver_nginx
            - nginx_reverse_proxy
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        restart: always
        command:
            - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
            - --sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - ./mysql/dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - ./mysql/etc_mysql:/etc/mysql/conf.d
            - mysql_vol:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - webserver_nginx

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links:
            - db:db
        ports:
            - ${PHPMYADMIN_PORT}:80
        networks:
            - webserver_nginx
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            UPLOAD_LIMIT: 64M
volumes:
    mysql_vol:
        external: false
networks:
  webserver_nginx:
  nginx_reverse_proxy:
    name: network_nginx_reverse_proxy
    external: true
```

default.conf of the nginx webserver:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _ webserver_nginx mysite.com localhost;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile of nginx webserver

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

From the nginx proxy I can ping the webserver with success and once I visit mysite.com, I find no logs in `docker logs -f webserver_nginx` but in `docker logs -f nginx-service` I find: `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.71.103.46, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.5:80/", host: "mysite.com"`

What am I missing here?
I bet it has something to do with the two config files for the servers but no clue what setting is wrong here.